# Visual leak detector does not report memory leak

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, memory-leaks

Using MSVC 2019, CMAKE, VSCODE to test the visual leak detector in C++ simple test fails to report memory leaks
What am I doing wrong here?
here is the code I have created

1. CMAKE

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0) 
> project(testing VERSION 0.1.0)
> include(CTest) enable_testing()
> add_executable(testing main.cpp)
> include_directories("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Visual Leak Detector\\include")
> set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}) set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}) 
> include(CPack)
> ```

MAIN.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#define VLD_FORCE_ENABLE
#include<vld.h>


int main(int, char**) {
    int *x = new int;
    char *c = new char;
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Visual Leak Detector read settings from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak  Detector\vld.ini 
Visual Leak Detector Version 2.5.7 installed. 
Hello, world! 
No memory leaks detected. Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
```

Comment: Maybe your compiler optimized those two lines with `new` away, since you aren't using those variables for anything.  Optimizing compilers can do amazing things these days.

Comment: I would compare it to another C++ profiler (Deleaker, or a similar one). For instance, if a PDB file was not available, VLD would not be able to show stack traces. Ensure that you debug a Debug build with disabled optimization and enabled frame pointers (it is important for 32-bit builds).

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem, and it was because I had Address Sanitizer turned on.

I turned it off (as it is in the picture) and everything started working OK again with VLD.

Presumably Address Sanitizer messes up the memory hooks VLD uses.
This might also apply to any other memory checking settings you have enabled.

[image]